# Karate: While Validating The Response Not Able To Get The Correct Value

Tags: automation, karate, web-api-testing

Here I Have Defined A Few Variables:

- def qantity1 = '1'
- def price1 = '14.49'
- def qantity2 = '1'
- def price2 = '14.49'
- def OutstandingAmount = qantity1 * price1 + qantity2 * price2

I'm expecting The Response Of Above Calculations To Come Out As '28.98' But I'm Getting It As 28.98 . Here Is An Actual Response From Console,

> $.total.outstandingAmount, actual: '28.98', expected: 28.98, reason: not equal (String : Double)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the message is clear isn't it, you are matching a string with a number.

You can read this for reference: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#type-conversion

Solution:

```
* def OutstandingAmount = (qantity1 * price1 + qantity2 * price2) + ''
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, I just checked that I was making a mistake, I have implemented your solution and it worked for me.